# Having a problem creating transparentToolbar

Tags: android

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Build
import android.view.View
import android.view.Window
import android.view.WindowManager

class zz {


    private fun transparentToolbar() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
            setWindowFlag(this, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, true)
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            setWindowFlag(this, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, false)
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        }
    }

    private fun setWindowFlag(activity: Activity, bits: Int, on: Boolean) {
        val win = activity.window
        val winParams = win.attributes
        if (on) {
            winParams.flags = winParams.flags or bits
        } else {
            winParams.flags = winParams.flags and bits.inv()
        }
        win.attributes = winParams
    }
}
```

this are the errors i got
Type mismatch: inferred type is zz but Activity was expected
Unresolved reference: getWindow
line 15 and 21,(**this**) line 18 and 22 (**getwindow**)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAWta.png)

Answer (score 0):

in your first method `this` refers to current object receiver, which in your case is the `zz` class, `getWindow()` reference is not resolved because there's no such method available in the receiver `zz` class, but in `Activity` class implementation it has the method so you will need an `Activity` instance to be able to call `getWindow()`

in your second method it expect to receive `Activity` as the argument so the type mismatch because `zz` doesn't inherit from or is the expected `Activity` class

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the default toolbar create a new toolbar using the widget:

Firstly remove the Toolbar from your app style

From

```xml
<style name="Theme.<AppName>" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.ActionBar">
```

To

```xml
<style name="Theme.<AppName>" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

Add a custom layout style to your theme.xml

```xml
<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">#00000000</item>
</style>
```

Then add a toolbar widget to your activity

```xml
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:theme="@style/CustomActionBar"/>
```

This should do it!